# Compiler take too much time to build in SwiftIU

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have enough knowledge about Storyboard, now I am using SwiftUI first time, I have already designed 4 screens for my app but now compiler take too much time to build code every time. It is very painful process.

My system is MacBook Pro 2015, with 500GB Flash Drive and 8gb ram.
I am using Xcode 11.1 and Catalina 10.15.1

What can I do so that build time will increase or something else?

Comment: Try to decompose your *designed 4 screens* for many small simple subcomponents, it will compile much faster.

Comment: After update my Xcode to 11.4 it's running well and compile time much faster now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a couple of flags to help you find slow areas.

Add to `Build Settings > Swift Compiler - Custom Flags > Other Swift Flags`

```
-Xfrontend -warn-long-function-bodies=<limit>
-Xfrontend -warn-long-expression-type-checking=<limit>
```

with `<limit>` being a number. I usually start at 400 and work my way down.

Some SwiftUI "tricks" that seem to help.

1. Defining types

```
    let string: String = ""
```

Takes less time to compile than

```
    let string = ""
```

2. Conditionals

```
switch myBool{
case true:
   //Something 1
case false:
   //Something 2
}
```

Is more efficient than

```
if myBool {
    //Something 1
} else {
    //Something 2
}
```

or

```
myBool ? /*Something 1 */ : /*Something 2 */
```